# Proving the sum of the shaded areas is equal to the incircle (in an equilateral triangle).

Tags: proof-explanation

[image]

I have worked through proving all the basic properties of the triangle, but I am confused about the concluding statement the author makes after this:

‘The relation R = 2r, which is a consequence of the coincidence of the circumcenter (intersection of perpendicular bisectors) and the incenter (inter- section of angle bisectors) with the centroid (intersection of medians which trisect one another), is but an outer manifestation of the hidden inner rela- tions of Figure 2.1. It immediately implies that the area of the annular region between the circumcircle and the incircle is three times the area of the latter. ***In turn, this leads directly to the beautiful relation that the sum of the shaded areas equals the area of the incircle!’***

I think I understand the first part of his statement, but it is the bit in bold I am unsure about. How do we reach the conclusion that the shaded areas sum to the area of the incircle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\eqalign{
  & A_{\,R}  = 4A_{\,r}   \cr 
  & {1 \over 3}\left( {A_{\,R}  - A} \right) + {1 \over 3}\left( {A - A_{\,r} } \right) = {1 \over 3}\left( {A_{\,R}  - A_{\,r} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 3}\left( {4A_{\,r}  - A_{\,r} } \right) = A_{\,r}  \cr} 
$$

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense!